# A high-temperature isolated neutron star could be super-Eddington?

Tags: astrophysics, neutron-star

If the surface temperature of a young neutron star is hot enough, say, several KeV, its blackbody radiation could be super-[Eddington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington_luminosity)?

Did any paper discuss this scenario before?